# Making a button do something

Tags: javascript, html, button, drop-down-menu

Alright, so I have this little google app I'm trying to put together and am going to have it be based off of crib notes.  There's a text field with a nonfunctioning button that says Add, two radio buttons, and two dropdown menus each either for a book or story.  When I have a radio button checked, text in my text field, and click Add, I'm wanting the text to be sent to one of the dropdown menus.
Here's my HTML so far

```
    <h1>Crib Reader</h1>

<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 134px; ">
            <input type="radio" name="Reader" value="Book" style="vertical-align: middle" checked="checked">Book
            <input type="radio" name="Reader" value="Story" style="vertical-align: middle">Story
        </td>
        <td style="width: 162px; "><input type="text" name="Name" style="height: 20px;"></td>
        <td> <button type="button">Add</button> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br></br>
<table align="center" style="width: 316px; ">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 115px; ">
            Books<br></br>
            <select id="Books" style="width: 100px; ">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <button type="button">Load</button>
        </td>

        <td style="width: 115px; ">
            Stories<br></br>
            <select id="Stories" style="width: 100px; ">
                <option value=""></option>
            </select>
        </td>
                    <td>
            <button type="button">Load</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<hr>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This post was *really* confusing until someone fixed the formatting, please be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the **ADD** button:
HTML:

```
<table align="center">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 134px; ">
            <input type="radio" name="Reader" value="Book" style="vertical-align: middle" checked="checked">Book
            <input type="radio" name="Reader" value="Story" style="vertical-align: middle">Story
        </td>
        <td style="width: 162px; "><input type="text" name="Name" style="height: 20px;"></td>
        <td> <button type="button" id="add">Add</button> </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Js:

Capture click event and check which radio button is checked and add value in select option accordingly

```
$("#add").on("click",function(){
 if($('input[name="Reader"]:checked').val() == "Book"){
  $("#Books").append("<option>"+$("input[name='Name']").val()+"</option>");
  }else{
  $("#Stories").append("<option>"+$("input[name='Name']").val()+"</option>");
 }
})
```

Comment: I understand this, but where do I put this code, I can't seem to find a Java area to make this code actually work.

Comment: What do mean by Java area? In javascript keep my js in document.ready function